# Show that ${a + b\pi : a, b \in \mathbb{Q}}$ does not qualify as a field extension

Tags: proof-writing, extension-field

How do I show that ${a + b\pi : a, b \in \mathbb{Q}}$ does not qualify as a field extension using $\sqrt{r}$?

Comment: I don't know what $r$ is nor how you want to use its root, but you can show that your set is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: @Wojowu Can you please show me your method? Showing that the set in not closed under multiplication. It will allow me to tackle a lot of other problems with your approach..

Comment: Well, $\pi$ is in $\Bbb Q + \pi\Bbb Q$, but $\pi\cdot\pi$ is not, since that would imply $\pi^2 = a + b\pi$, but that would mean that $\pi$ is root of $x^2-bx - a$, which is contradiction since $\pi$ is transcedental.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what $\sqrt{r}$ is. But suppose that the above is a field. Then $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is in there. So in particular $\frac{1}{\pi}=a+b \pi$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q},b \ne0$. This implies that $b\pi^2+a\pi-1=0$ which implies that $\pi$ is algebraic . This is a contradiction.